# Substituting mentions in a String

Tags: java, string

I wrote an algortihm that gets a list of entries of the form `(word,(lower,upper))` as input and is supposed to substitute mentions in a text in the range of `(lower,upper)` through `word`.
Example:
text: "Gauß was a german mathematican." 1. ("He",(0,3)), 2. ("physicist",(18,29))
Result: "He was a german physicist."
Unfortunately I do not find the mistake within my algorithm.

```
private static String substituteByOffset(String text, List<Pair<String, Pair<Integer, Integer>>> mentions) {
    int offset = 0;
    for (Pair<String, Pair<Integer, Integer>> entry : mentions) {
        String subst = entry.first;
        Pair<Integer, Integer> offsets = entry.second;
        Integer lower = offsets.first;
        Integer upper = offsets.second;
        text = text.substring(0, lower + offset) + subst + text.substring(upper + offset, text.length());
        offset = subst.length() - (upper - lower);
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: I am using `import edu.stanford.nlp.util.Pair;` for the Pair implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated previous, I made a mistake in the question above, but nevertheless the mistake I was looking for was the missing addition of the offset to the new offset.

```
private static String substituteByOffset(String text, List<Pair<String, Pair<Integer, Integer>>> mentions) {
    int offset = 0;
    for (Pair<String, Pair<Integer, Integer>> entry : mentions) {
        String subst = entry.first;
        Pair<Integer, Integer> offsets = entry.second;
        Integer lower = offsets.first;
        Integer upper = offsets.second;
        text = text.substring(0, lower + offset) + subst + text.substring(upper + offset, text.length());
        offset = subst.length() - (upper - lower) + offset;
    }
    return text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) Returns a new string that is a
>   substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified
>   beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1. Thus
>   the length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex.

Thus:

```
"Gauß was a german mathematican.".substring(0,3) : "Gau"
"Gauß was a german mathematican.".substring(0,4) : "Gauß"
```

Trying with these inputs `1. ("He",(0,3)), 2. ("physicist",(18,29))` results like this:

"He**ß** was a german physicist**n**."

This inputs below will give the right result:

```
String text = "Gauß was a german mathematican.";
List<Pair<String, Pair<Integer, Integer>>> mentions = Arrays.asList(
        new Pair("He", new Pair<Integer, Integer>(0,4)), 
        new Pair("physicist", new Pair<Integer, Integer>(18,30)));

substituteByOffset(text, mentions); // prints "He was a german physicist."
```

Comment: Still the algorithm fails for larger inputs. Any ideas?